# How can i consume restful api from grails controller?

Tags: java, api, grails

I have purchased bulk sms from a mobile company.They provided me api documentation.I can send message using the api via ajax calling.But for security issues i want to use the api from server side instead of client side.

I already tried grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder but didn't get proper documentation.

in plugin dependency i used : compile "org.grails.plugins:rest-client-builder:2.1.1"

I want to consume the api from my grails controller

Comment: Could you provide some code and tell us what you have tried so far?
An example would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems very broad.  There are loads of ways to make rest calls from any JVM app, Grails apps included.

A common approach is to use `RestBuilder` from `org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client`.

```
def rest = new RestBuilder()

// generate a GET request
def response = rest.get('https://someurl.com/someuri')
def json = response.json
def firstName = json.firstName
def lastName = json.lastName
// etc...

// generate a POST request
response = rest.post('https://someurl.com/someuri') {
    // this results in the body of the request being
    // {"firstName":"Jeff","lastName":"Brown"} and
    // the content type being set to application/json
    json {
        firstName = 'Jeff'
        lastName = 'Brown'
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally the below code solved my purpose.Thanks @Jeff Scott Brown  for your help. `def rest = new RestBuilder()
      MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
        form.add("UserID", "****")
        form.add("Passwor", "******")
        form.add("stuID", "*******")
        def resp = rest.post("url") {
            accept JSONObject, 'application/json'
            contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            body(form)
        }
       def json = resp.json
       System.out.println(json)`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/1f68ba4cf0244d4f96d5c621b2f98e53

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13OxWb_oBUVo2ReKrBCW_BkDsebka7kYLbtUwFmdAT5Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you are describing.  Seems to work fine, but maybe I am missing something that is in your project.  I am glad you got it working.